# Add additional rows using an SQL query

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]

```
SELECT distinct [product_group]
      ,[product_type_name]
  FROM [Yield_Reporting].[dbo].[d_product]
```

For every product_group entry I want to have another product_type_name = AllType

So the resulting table should look like this,

[image]

I can't figure out how to make that result using an SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hard-code `AllType` string for the `product_type_name` value and  `UNION` this with your existing `DISTINCT` values you can get your expected result.

Working Demo with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @d_product TABLE (product_group VARCHAR (200), product_type_name VARCHAR (200));

INSERT INTO @d_product( product_group, product_type_name) VALUES
('BARE_SILICON', 'BARE_SILICON'),
('Black_Mamba', 'Black_Mamba'),
('BURIN-IN_WAFER', 'BURIN-IN_WAFER'),
('CALVIN', 'CALVIN_BLK');

SELECT DISTINCT [product_group], [product_type_name] FROM @d_product
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT [product_group], 'AllType' FROM @d_product
```

Output:

```
product_group      product_type_name
---------------------------------------
BARE_SILICON       AllType
BARE_SILICON       BARE_SILICON
Black_Mamba        AllType
Black_Mamba        Black_Mamba
BURIN-IN_WAFER     AllType
BURIN-IN_WAFER     BURIN-IN_WAFER
CALVIN             AllType
CALVIN             CALVIN_BLK
```

Comment: this is perfect! I wasn't able to figure out the same when using UNION. Thanks so much!

Comment: @tinker: You are welcome, happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a constant

```
SELECT distinct [product_group] , 'Alltype'  
FROM [Yield_Reporting].[dbo].[d_product]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The answer is here correct here too. But the other answer by ArulKumar is more complete with UNION.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with [GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx), eg

```
SELECT [product_group], ISNULL( [product_type_name] , 'AllType' ) product_group
FROM @d_product
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( ( product_group, [product_type_name] ), product_group )
```

This results in only one table/index scan rather than the two required for the `UNION`, although I don't see much difference in my performance test.  Thanks to @Arulkumar for DDL/DML which I've used for this example.